# Powershell 5.1: how to monitor if a .zip file is currently locked or not?

Tags: powershell

```
function IsFileLocked {
    param($fileToCheck)

    try {
        $stream = [System.IO.File]::Open($fileToCheck, 'Open', 'Read')
        $stream.Close()
        return $false 
    }
    catch {
        return $true   # File is locked
    }
}
```

The above function works OK when `$fileToCheck` is not a .zip file. But further down the script i have this line:

```
Compress-Archive -Path $filePath -DestinationPath $zipPath
```

$zipPath represents a .zip file. And right beneath it i invoke this function again:

```
$fileLocked = IsFileLocked -fileToCheck $zipPath
```

But apparently in reality it never gets executed. The file does get compressed, but no other routines below the `Compress-Archive..`. line are executed.

Here is more code for reference:

```
function IsFileLocked {
    param($fileToCheck)

    try {
        $stream = [System.IO.File]::Open($filePath, 'Open', 'Read')
        $stream.Close()
        return $false 
    }
    catch {
        return $true   # File is locked
    }
}

$fileLocked = IsFileLocked -fileToCheck $filePath

if ($fileLocked) {
    Write-Host "File is locked. Entering the while-loop"
} else {
    Write-Host "File is NOT locked"
}

while ($fileLocked) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    $fileLocked = IsFileLocked -fileToCheck $filePath
}

Write-Host "File is no longer locked. Proceeding to archive it."            

$zipFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($filePath) + ".zip"

$zipPath = Join-Path (Get-Item $filePath).DirectoryName $zipFileName

Write-Host "Here is FILE PATH: $filePath"

Write-Host "Here is ZIP PATH: $zipPath"

Compress-Archive -Path $filePath -DestinationPath $zipPath

$fileLocked = IsFileLocked -fileToCheck $zipPath

if ($fileLocked) {
    Write-Host "File is still being archived. Waiting..."
} else {
    Write-Host "Zip file is NOT locked"
}

while ($fileLocked) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    $fileLocked = IsFileLocked -fileToCheck $zipPath
}

Write-Host ("Compressed and saved as: " + $zipPath) 

Write-Host "Zipping is complete. Proceeding to send it."
```

The output is:

```
File is locked. Entering the while-loop
File is no longer locked. Proceeding to archive it.
Here is FILE PATH: F:\asset_gm_EXPORT\_Transfer\a00000009.gdbtable
Here is ZIP PATH: F:\asset_gm_EXPORT\_Transfer\a00000009.zip
```